# Right Partition vs Right Graph

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, set-partition

I came up with this problem yesterday: Let $R$ be a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $P$ a finite partition of $R$ into rectangles such that every one of them has its sides parallel to the sides of $R$ and $P_c$ the set of the centers of the rectangles in $P$. Construct a graph as follows: Draw a segment between any two different $r_c,r_c'\in P_c$ iff their respective rectangles share more than a vertex. We call this graph (for instance) *The Right Graph* of $R$ (haven't actually looked if there is already a name for such graph), and denote it as $G_R$.

Given a rectangle $R$, finding its right graph is not that complicated, so my question is, what are the conditions for a graph $G$ to be the right graph of a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ??[image: example]

Comment: This looks awfully like the [dual graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph) of a planar graph (except for your not considering the outer [infinite] face, I guess).

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right... though this a bit more restrictive version.